# Externals in VisualSVNServer

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-externals

I'm using VisualSVNServer. I've a svn repo (say: test1) with externals (say: test2). Everything fine so far, when I checkout test1, test2 is automatically checked out to and placed inside my working copy of test1. Good.

But when looking into test1 using the web frontend of VisualSVNServer I see no hint that there is an external linked to that repo.

Is that the correct behaviour? Is there a way to see the externals - or at least hints that there are externals - in the web frontend?

Cheers and thanks,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

The web interface of VisualSVN Server 3.5 does not display external items added via `svn:externals`. However, this feature may be added in future server updates.